# Whenever I got to my new pages (http://www.cwmags.com/news) it requests login?

Tags: users

I have two news pages on different domain names (different content) using the same template. http://www.cwmags.co.uk/news and http://www.cwmags.com.

I have check .htaccess (301 redirects), CHMOD permissions and on both sites they are identical (apart from difference in domain name).
Authentication Required Log In required.  Clicking cancel is sufficient to access the web pages.

Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: I get the login box too. It seems to come from a request to `http://www.cwmags.com/tracker/twatch/remote/js_logger.php`, so not from your main WordPress installation.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually tracked it down to a Wordpress add-in.  There was an error in the Google Analytic code that had an extra script attached which should not have been there.

Thanks for help and advice.